# Harmonic Gauge Condition

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, gravity, differential-geometry, gauge

I was recently looking at Sean Carrols notes on G.R.: https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/March01/Carroll3/Carroll6.html , where in eqn 6.37 he states

$$\text{"The Harmonic Gauge Condition: $\square x^{\mu}=0$" }$$

I have always seen the Harmonic Gauge Condition written as:

$$0=\Gamma _{{\beta \gamma }}^{{\alpha }}g^{{\beta \gamma }}\,.$$

I am wondering how to show that these are equivalent.

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: This is also already covered in his notes, specifically equation (4.85)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The action of $\Box$ on $x^\mu$ is defined by treating $x^\mu$ as a scalar (even though its not). Then,
\begin{align}
\Box x^\mu &= g^{\alpha\beta} \nabla_\alpha \nabla_\beta x^\mu \\
&= g^{\alpha\beta} [ \partial_\alpha \partial_\beta x^\mu - \Gamma^\lambda_{\alpha\beta} \partial_\lambda x^\mu ] \\
&= - g^{\alpha\beta} \Gamma^\lambda_{\alpha\beta} \delta^\mu_\lambda \\
&= - g^{\alpha\beta} \Gamma^\mu_{\alpha\beta} .
\end{align}
Thus, the harmonic gauge condition $\Box x^\mu = 0$ is equivalent to $g^{\alpha\beta} \Gamma^\mu_{\alpha\beta} = 0$.

Comment: I think you mean treating $\partial x$ as a vector (or else there would be a lot more terms here).

Comment: @Eletie I did mean scalar and I fixed it.

Comment: Cool, just checking

Comment: @Eletie thanks!!!